# Does statistically simple algos qualify as AI algos?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, k-means, pareto-distribution

We have a customer purchase transaction history data with variables like below

recency - how recently they bought?
frequency - How often they bought?
monetary - How much value did they bring to the company?

and also few more variables like product id, purchase date etc.

We would like to do the below projects

a) Customer segmentation

b) Customer Lifetime value prediction

c) Customer Churn

So, for all the three above objectives, I thought I will use the below approaches

a) Jenks Natural breaks optimization

b) and c) Buy Till you die models

So, now my question is our superiors ask me to do AI projects but if I do projects using above algorithm, does it qualify as AI project?

Am confused. Because AI comes from statistics and these models also are backed by statistical proofs etc.

So, does the above approaches qualify as AI algos? would it be appropriate to call them as AI algos? Considering jenks breaks is simple to implement, can that be called an AI algorithm?

Comment: Who cares? *A rose by any other name would smell as sweet*

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - I viewed your profile and would like to contact you for some paid consulting. Would you be interested to help? Howver, I am unable to decipher your email address from the profile. I don't know what does public seed mean?

Comment: You can find my public seed by searching some of my posts. Try site search with the keywords "kjetil public seed"

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - by public seed, do you mean the user id? When I search using the keywords that you shared, it returns zero results.  Anyway, I found your user id and sent an email (kjetil11887@gmail.com) but it returned due to incorrect address. Basically, I don't know what does public seed mean?

Comment: See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67350/downsampling-proportions-for-logistic-regression/364696#364696  What is 7*11*13 ?

Comment: Great. Thanks. Sent you an email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no universally accepted definition of *artificial intelligence*. Since this directive came from your superiors, it does not matter whether anyone here considers the projects you've proposed to be artificial intelligence projects; what matters is whether your superiors consider them to be artificial intelligence projects.

I would suggest presenting them a high-level overview of the projects you have in mind and their possible benefits to your company and let them decide whether they're the kinds of projects they want you spending your time on.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This is really the only answer. +1

Comment: thanks for the response. Since there is no universally accepted definition, calling jenks breaks as AI algo wouldn't be highly inappropriate? I don't wish to oversell something. Hence, I was confused. What would be a better and appropriate terms to use for such algos (just statistical algos)?

Comment: No, not inappropriate, in my opinion, but potentially should include a caveat: that it's a "clustering" or "grouping" algorithm. These kinds of algorithms are often found in texts titled "Artificial Intelligence", especially older ones, but, it's not the first thing that comes to mind for people with a more limited or superficial exposure to the field. You're right to be careful about the language you use. Calling something "artificial intelligence" could be overselling something depending on the background of the audience. Statistical clustering algorithm would be absolutely appropriate.